# Error code 500 on new subdomain in cpanel

Tags: php, .htaccess, deployment

I've created and added a sub-domain to my website which is called mis.
The project is implemented with laravel 5.6 and php 7.2.
When I load the www.mis.example.com, it gives me: 
**mis.example.com** is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500

There is a code of .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews -Indexes
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Can you guys help me with this error?

Comment: Have you checked your PHP error logs? I think it should be the first step.

Comment: Also check apache error logs, incase it is an apache setup issue.

Comment: actually, could not find :(

Answer (score 0):

Do some optimization - https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/deployment#optimization

```
php composer install --optimize-autoloader --no-dev

php composer dump-autoload

php artisan config:cache
php artisan route:cache
php artisan config:clear
php artisan view:clear
```

Comment: You need to use SSH

Answer (score 0):

Folow Step

**1] check your php info**

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

**2]  search "mbstring"**

[image]

if mbstring still not installed, you can ask the provider to installed that.

if already installed and still got the error 500, better you must check your php version in phpinfo(). And clear your cache with php artisan command. when you have a permission to shell, you can try to check your php version with command "php -v" and see the default php with which php.

Comment: where to run this code?
the main domain is working good, the current php version is 7.2